# The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to code for pop up message box for displaying message for successful record insertion in C#.net

**Error** :

> The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the  namespace
>   'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**Code** :

```
 global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

Comment: Forget a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`? (Project->Add Reference)

Comment: Does System.Windows show up in your usings? Are you running on Windows or Mono?

Comment: You tagged your question "asp.net-mvc-3". Do you want to display a MessageBox in the Webapplication? If this is the case, this will not work, since this are 2 cmpleteley different technologies. If this is not the case, I guess you are missing the System.Windows.Forms assembly reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not missing any DLL , It seems like you are using the wrong type of project.

Comment: LOL I like this answer because a) its phenomenally correct and b) he's accessing a MessageBox in a web app

Comment: What kind of project is required? What things do we need to click in VS to make this magic work?

Answer (score 17):

If you are using MS Visual Studio:

1. Right click on the Project
2. Select "Add Reference..."
3. Navigate to the ".NET" tab
4. Find "System.Windows.Forms" and select it
5. Click OK.

P. S.: Additionally, I had to do the same with "System.Drawing" for everything to work correctly in my first GUI Windows program.

Answer (score 10):

`global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");` in an ASP.NET MVC application? And where did you expect this message box to pop out?

In an ASP.NET MVC application you could use client side javascript to show message boxes.

For example inside your view you could put the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Test');
</script>
```

And when you navigate to the corresponding controller action the user will be greeted with the message box.

Answer (score 2):

Incredibly I got this error when one of my class libraries has 'System' in its own namespace. MyCompany.Foo.Bar.Client.System as my assembly namespace must have cause a clash somewhere. Removing the 'System' from my namespace solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2012, Framework 4.0 for windows application. I was also getting the following message:
'the type or namespace 'windows' does not exist'

To fix this problem, I added reference to Windows.Forms.dll. After that I can display message box using the following code

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Completed successfully");